# Can not set background color of android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar

Tags: android, android-layout, android-design-library

I create app from the template with **Design Support Library** and gonna change the color of the `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar` to **pure red**.

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="#ff0000"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />
```

It works, but color is D62628 instead FF0000. What's wrong?

**Update:** Ok, I try to do it via **colorPrimary**. Set color in `colors.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="colorPrimary">#ffff0000</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#303F9F</color>
    <color name="colorAccent">#FF4081</color>
</resources>
```

**The same history:**

[image: screenshot]

Comment: you are passing  '#ffff0000' put this '#ff0000' and then check

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    local:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    local:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

and add in ur color.xml

```
<resources>
    <color name="colorPrimary">#FF0000</color>


</resources>
```

Comment: So, I have #25183d in styles and #1B152D on screenshot. Who changes the color??

Comment: which  background color u wants to set  mention that at   <color name="colorPrimary">YOUR_COLOR</color>

Comment: <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>      addd this instead of adding hashcode in style.xml

Comment: which hashcode u want to set in your Toolbar background ?

Comment: @Harshad I want to get #ff0000.

Comment: The main problem for me that designers give me the color of toolbar, but I can not set it. I could recalculate if it required, but what is the rule?

Comment: let me explain... if u wants to set a background color in a toolbar then u should set it in  <color name="colorPrimary">#ffff0000</color>,  tag

Comment: i tried ur  colorcode in my app\s toolbar tatz working fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this in your **onCreate()** method.

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            Window window = getWindow();
            window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
            window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
            window.setStatusBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
        } 
        setContentView(R.layout.your_layout);
.
.
.
}
```

Comment: Nope, the same color. :(

Comment: What you are putting in your **colorPrimary**. What is the hash code??

Answer (score 0):

The answer will be not about Android, it will be about the tools. Color picker in Android Studio takes wrong color. As I understand it takes color from screen, that affected by calibration settings, not from screenshot.

When I picked color inside the Gimp editor, it shows me the same color that I set in styles.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/wrs_color_primary</item>
    ...
</style>
<color name="wrs_color_primary">#ff9900</color>
```

[image]